# How do I initialize a merged tuple to a init function?

Tags: python, pandas

I need to pass the variables textArray and labelArray to the Review class so that I can call a single review like review[2].score.

```
reviews = merge(Review(textArray, labelArray) 
reviews[2].score
```

gives a syntax Error

```
class Review:
    def __init__(self, text, score):
        self.text = text
        self.score = score

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

frame = pd.read_csv('fake_or_real_news.csv')
frame.head()

frame["text"]
textArray = frame["text"].values
print(textArray)

labelArray = frame["label"].values

reviews = []


def merge(textArray, labelArray): 

    a = [(textArray[i], labelArray[i]) for i in range(0, len(textArray))] 
    return a 

reviews = merge(textArray, labelArray) 
reviews[2]
```

Comment: `merge(Review(textArray, labelArray)` is missing the closing paren.

Comment: Did you mean `merge(textArray, labelArray)`?

Comment: I want to pass the tuple reviews to the class Review.

Comment: You showed two lines of code that gave a syntax error. This code is not in the example you gave below. I don't know how things called "textArray" and "labelArray" would be useful to a class tracking "text" and "score". But I do know that those first two lines are indeed invalid syntax.

Comment: I am really sorry if I can't make my question clear. I am new to this.
What I want to do is pass the tuple reviews(it contains textArray and labelArray) to the init function so that I can access each labelArray by reviews[i].score

Comment: So, for instance, textArray[0] and labelArray[0] should be used to make one Review, and repeat for all items in those arrays?

Comment: Your merge function is just the zip function. If you find it difficult to formulate the question, how about showing examples of the expected output? Like `text_array = ["hi", "ho"]`, `label_array = [0.1, 0.2]`, is converted to `[Review(text = "hi", score = 0.1), Review(text = "ho", score = 0.2)` or so? (That would be done by `map(Review, text_array, label_array)`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will give you a list of `Review` built from "text" and "label" columns in your CSV file. After building a test dataframe (hope I got that right) I used `zip` to iterate the two columns in unison (replacing your `merge`) to build the reviews.

```
class Review:
    def __init__(self, text, score):
        self.text = text
        self.score = score

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# frame = pd.read_csv('fake_or_real_news.csv')

# test dataframe
frame = pd.DataFrame([["Text0", "Label0"], 
                      ["Text1", "Label1"], 
                      ["Text2", "Label2"]],
    columns=["text", "label"])

reviews = [Review(text, label) for text, label in zip(frame.text, frame.label)]
for review in reviews:
    print(review.text, review.score)
```

Answer (score 0):

change your last piece of code to this

```
   def merge(): 
    for i in textArray:
       this=textArray.index(i)
       reviews.append((textArray[this], labelArray[this]))
   merge()
   print(reviews)
```

Comment: This is giving me an AttributeError     
AttributeError   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-92-334881e42fc5> in <module>
      3        this=textArray.index(i)
      4        reviews.append((textArray[this], labelArray[this]))
----> 5 merge()
      6 print(reviews)

<ipython-input-92-334881e42fc5> in merge()
      1 def merge():
      2     for i in textArray:
----> 3        this=textArray.index(i)
      4        reviews.append((textArray[this], labelArray[this]))
      5 merge()

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'index'